# Portable color codes with printf?

Tags: colors, escape-characters, printf, tput

There is a [color codes script on GitHub](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt/blob/master/colors.sh) suitable for sourcing, which I am modifying for my own purposes.

---

**Background**

I have an odd mix of environments to work in, from a Mac OS terminal, to various Linux distributions, and even to a MobaXterm on my Windows work laptop.  I'd like to get the color codes to a maximum portability for these environments

In MobaXterm, `tput setaf 2` (for example) doesn't work at all—it just says "Segmentation fault," though I see no ill effects.  Likewise, `echo '\e[4;32m'` doesn't work either; it just displays those literal characters.  (This is likely because it is BusyBox `echo`.)

`printf '\e[4;32m'` works, though.

---

The question:

**Is there any reason not to use `printf` in place of `tput` in *all* cases?**

Or put another way:

Is there any environment (or OS or shell) in which `printf` WON'T work to set terminal colors, but `tput` WILL?

Comment: `tput` looks up the correct codes for your terminal (these days, they're nearly all vt-100 compatible to varying degrees) in the `terminfo` or `termcap` database and uses them.  Using `printf` or `echo` or whatever to output colour codes is hard-coding them so that only work on the current terminal type (or compatible).  In this modern era that often doesn't matter (due to the near-universal use of vt-100 compatible terminals), but some people still use non-vt100 terminals or terminal emulators....anyway, hard-coding is pure evil.

Comment: btw, what's in your `TERM` and/or `TERMCAP` variables when logging in via MobaXterm?  It may be that your terminfo db has a bad (or non-existent?) entry for that $TERM.  Does `tput` work in Moba if you do something like `export TERM=xterm`?

Comment: @cas, `echo $TERM` shows `xterm` already.

Comment: I would guess that mobaxterm probably doesn't implement an xterm correctly.  Have you tried telling it to emulate different terminal types?  Perhaps vt-102 or vt-220?